# Можно ли установить любую из 14+ версий node.js в Windows 7?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Можно ли установить любую из 14+ версий node.js в Windows 7?

Если да, покажите, пожалуйста, правильный способ установки?

Comment: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: Официальный ответ: "К сожалению, Windows 7 достигла своего EOL, и мы больше не поддерживаем ее. Последняя версия node.js, протестированная на Win7, - 13.6.0.", но вы можете попробовать установить дистрибутив согласно [инструкции](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33000#issuecomment-644530517)